# yaml syntax error on adding list

Tags: yaml

I am trying to generate a yaml for a list of objects and I am getting errors stating wrong syntax

```
tables:
 table_ab:
  bankspecificparams:
  -
     issuer:"bank1"
     cardname:""
     expiredinterval:"90d"
     fields:
      - "a"
      - "b"
  -
     issuer:"bank2"
     cardname:""
     expiredinterval:"40d"
     fields:
      - "a"
      - "b"  
  - 
     issuer:"bank3"
     cardname:"name1"
     expiredinterval:"40d"
     fields:
      - "a"
      - "b"
```

The following yaml snytax seems to be incorrect. I am not sure what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

### This was an issue with space after colon.

```
tables: 
  table_ab: 
    bankspecificparams: 
      - 
        cardname: ""
        expiredinterval: 90d
        fields: 
          - a
          - b
        issuer: bank1
      - 
        cardname: ""
        expiredinterval: 40d
        fields: 
          - a
          - b
        issuer: bank2
      - 
        cardname: name1
        expiredinterval: 40d
        fields: 
          - a
          - b
        issuer: bank3
```

adding spaces resolved the issue